# angularjs: directive on-the-fly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I achieve something like the following using angular? I've tried several techniques but the docs don't help much...

```
<div id="#parent">
  <!-- this is component definition, won't be rendered -->
  <component id="tbl">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in env.items"><td>{{item.label}}</td></tr>
      <tbody>
    </table>
  </component>

  ...
  <!-- 
    this should only work if a component is registered within this parent, 
    ie '#parent' and would render the component as defined above
  -->
  <component ref="table" env="myCtx" />
</div>
```

the controller would be something like this:

```
<script>
 //ctrl definition
 funcion Ctrl(scope) {
   scope.myCtx = { 
     items: [{label: "xxx"}, {label: "yyy"}]
   }
 }
</script>
```

Basically, I want to define a directive on-the-fly and I want it to be accessible only inside the `#parent` node (altough this is optional). I got stuck because I expected to be able to inject **angular-aware** html (ie, with `<h1>{{blah}}</h1>`) either in the `compile` function or within the `transclude` function.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just have to scratch your own itch: [http://jsfiddle.net/mping/6fwJ3/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/mping/6fwJ3/)

Ended up taking a different route. I use a parent `controller`, and two directives, one for defining the component and the other for calling it.